# how to find the internet connection type whether Wifi or LAN connection through java code not with android

Tags: java, network-programming

public class ConnetionType {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {NetworkInterface ni=new NetworkInterface();

}
```

}

Comment: Try to do a little more of research please.

Comment: You haven't exactly given us much to go on, just a peice of skeleton code. Try writing some code and asking us to fix a problem. Not write your code for you!!

Comment: Sorry for the code,Actually in our web application we want to show the user's internet connection type to user whether user using Wifi or ethernet...we want to implement this in java...i am trying through java api i am't getting solution..plz respond......thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

public class networktest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface>eni=NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(eni.hasMoreElements()){
        NetworkInterface nii=eni.nextElement();
        if(nii.isUp())
                System.out.println("you are connected to:"+nii.getDisplayName());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows computer you can use the command line:

```
try {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh interface show interface");
   String line;
   java.io.BufferedReader input = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   int counter = 0;
   while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      counter++;
      if (counter > 3) { // The first lines are headlines, so it can be ignored
         System.out.println(line);
      }
   }
   input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/check-if-wifi-is-connected/) for explanation about the command.